# How do I convert a RangeInclusive to a Range?

Tags: rust, range

So obviously I could do something like:

```
impl From<RangeInclusive<u32>> for Range<u32>{
    fn from(r: RangeInclusive<u32>) -> Self {
        (*r.start()..(r.end()+1))
    }
}
```

However I was wondering if there was already a standard function for this?(I was unable to find anything in docs/ after a quick Google).
If not how would one go about implementing this for every num type, and would such an implementation be welcome to rust, or is there a reason why this is not already implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not every `RangeInclusive` can be converted to a `Range`, which is a major reason for `RangeInclusive` to exist. For instance, `0u32..=u32::MAX` cannot be converted to `Range<u32>` because `u32::MAX + 1` is out of range for `u32`.

It's conceivable that `Range<u32>` could implement `TryFrom<RangeInclusive<u32>>`, but such conversion should rarely be necessary. Instead of converting between different kinds of ranges, you should usually write generic APIs using [`RangeBounds`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html).